# Compare two List<int>

Tags: c#

I am writing a small program to compare two List. If the values are the same, I add them to list dups, if they are different, I add them to distinct. I noticed that some of my values are added and some are not, and after debugging for awhile, I am not certain what the problem is. Can someone shed a little light? Thanks.

```
        List<int> groupA = new List<int>();
        List<int> groupB = new List<int>();

        List<int> dups = new List<int>();
        List<int> distinct = new List<int>();

        groupA.Add(2);
        groupA.Add(24);
        groupA.Add(5);
        groupA.Add(72);
        groupA.Add(276);
        groupA.Add(42);
        groupA.Add(92);
        groupA.Add(95);
        groupA.Add(266);
        groupA.Add(42);
        groupA.Add(92);


        groupB.Add(5);
        groupB.Add(42);
        groupB.Add(95);

        groupA.Sort();
        groupB.Sort();

        for (int a = 0; a < groupA.Count; a++)
        {
            for (int b = 0; b < groupB.Count; b++)
            {
                groupA[a].CompareTo(groupB[b]);


                if (groupA[a] == groupB[b])
                {
                    dups.Add(groupA[a]);
                    groupA.Remove(groupA[a]);
                    groupB.Remove(groupB[b]);
                }

            }
            distinct.Add(groupA[a]);
        }
```

Comment: Could you post the expected results ?

Comment: I think you are removing group[b] to soon. Because your for works like this A1 -> B 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 etc, A2 -> b1 2 3 4 5 . If you remove a number from b, it wont be able to show up in dups or distinct. But thats just my instinct. :)

Comment: You're removing elements from the lists while iterating them, so the loop conditions (based on elements number) can be compromised...

Comment: These guys are correct. **Never modify a list while you are iterating over it**. It creates all manner of bugs. In other news: what is the CompareTo doing?  Also, why do you sort and then not take advantage of the fact that the lists are sorted?  Also: you can make this much more efficient by using hash sets instead of lists.

Comment: Eric, can you send me an example of a hash list?

Comment: @jpavlov What should happen with the value of 92 in groupA? Is that a duplicate or not?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I would use the [`Intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.intersect.aspx) and [`Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx) methods:

```
dups = groupA.Intersect(groupB).ToList();
distinct = groupA.Except(groupB).ToList();
```

Comment: Length of the list is important. var l1 = new List<long>() {1, 5, 6};  var l2 = new List<long>() { 6, 5, 1, 2 }; l2.Except(l1) => 2. l1.Except(l2) => nothing

Comment: As the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#overloads) stated: `This method returns those elements in first that don't appear in second. It doesn't return those elements in second that don't appear in first.`
That means if the `list2` contains all `list1`'s items and other items, `list1.Except(list2)` will return an empty collection.

Answer (score 15):

The title of the question is "Compare two List", some people who are interested in true/false only result will land to the question

use Enumerable.SequenceEqual Method

```c#
    if (listA.SequenceEqual(listB))
    {
       // they are equal
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

When you remove an item from a list, you move the index of the remaining element down.
In essence, you are skipping some items using a for loop.
Try using a while loop, and manually increment the counter when you are not deleting an item.

For example, the following code is incorrect

```
List<int> nums = new List<int>{2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11};

for (int i = 0; i < nums.Count; i++)
{
  if (nums[i] % 2 == 0)
    nums.Remove(nums[i]);
}
```

If will return the list `{4, 7, 10, 11}` instead of just `{7, 11}`.

It will not remove the value of 4, because, when I remove the value of 2, (for `i=0`) the `nums` list goes from

```
//index 0  1  2  3  4   5   6 
nums = {2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11}
```

to

```
//index 0  1  2  3  4   5
nums = {4, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11}
```

The loop finishes, the i is incremented to 1, and the next item referenced is `nums[1]`, which is not 4 as one would intuitively expect, but 6. So in effect the value of 4 is skipped, and the check is not executed.

You should be very, very careful each time when you are modifying the collection you are iterating. For example, the `foreach` statement will throw an exception if you even try this. In this case you could use a while like

```
List<int> nums = new List<int>{2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11};

int i = 0;
while (i < nums.Count)
{
  if (nums[i] % 2 == 0)
  {
    nums.Remove(nums[i])
  }      
  else
  {
    i++; //only increment if you are not removing an item
         //otherwise re-run the loop for the same value of i
  }  
}
```

of you could even fork the for, like

```
for (int i = 0; i < nums.Count; i++)
{
  if (nums[i] % 2 == 0)
  {
    nums.Remove(nums[i]);
    i--; //decrement the counter, so that it will stay in place
         //when it is incremented at the end of the loop
  }
}
```

Alternatively you could use linq, like this:

```
distinct.AddRange(groupA);
distinct.AddRange(groupB);
distinct = distinct.Distinct().ToList();
```

and

```
dups.AddRange(groupA);
dups.AddRange(groupB);

dups = dups.GroupBy(i => i)
           .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
           .Select(g => g.Key)
           .ToList();
```

Note that the LINQ code will not alter your existing groupA and groupB lists. If you just want to distinct them, you could just do

```
groupA = groupA.Distinct().ToList();
groupB = groupB.Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: Replace both for loops with a while loop?

Comment: I'll leave your implementation to you, but I've added an example that illustrates where your code goes wrong, and how to fix it.

Answer (score 5):

You can easily do it with Linq:

```
    List<int> dups = groupA.Intersect(groupB).ToList();
    List<int> distinct = groupA.Except(groupB).ToList();
```

(assuming I correctly understood what you were trying to do)

Answer (score 3):

You need to find the missing elements in both:

```
List<int> onlyInA = groupA.Except(groupB).ToList();
List<int> onlyInB = groupB.Except(groupA).ToList();
```

Or in a single linq:

```
List<int> missing = groupA.Except(groupB).Union(groupB.Except(groupA)).ToList()
```

Note - as with all linq, its worth pointing out that its not the most efficient way to do this. All list iterations have a cost. A longer-hand way of sorting both lists then iterating over them together would be quicker if the lists were REALLY large...